# Using Doxygen with PHP in Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, doxygen

**What does the main argument of the following statement explicitly mean?**

The manual says Doxygen supports only partially PHP. I would like to know what this means explicitly, since I could not find an answer to it in the homepage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a complete answer I could find either, but the state of PHP support is probably gradually improving. Here are some issues I've found, some of which may already be solved:

- [lack of namespace support](http://www.nabble.com/Support-for-PHP-namespaces-td19508377.html)
- [issues with magic methods](http://www.nabble.com/PHP-and-arbitrary-class-properties-td24080652.html#a24080652)
- [problems documenting functions with variable number of arguments](http://www.nabble.com/Two-PHP-related-questions%3A-using-%40var-and-handling-varargs-td14221842.html#a14221842)

Comment: You can add ["problems with heredoc"](http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg886561.html) to the list :)

Comment: As well as problems with documenting class members at all... it would probably be a better idea to use something like DocBlocks, APIGen, or PHPDoctor..